# Hacer una validación de que un usuario ya existe en la base de datos

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, angularjs

Necesito que cuando haga un nuevo usuario o edite al apretar al botón guardar y al recoger el dato input(usuario) que me diga que ese usuario ya existe en la base de datos. Estoy haciendo el servidor con java con un POJO, DAO y Servlet y el cliente con Javascript, Jquery, Angular.

Se que me dais a pedir código pero es muy extenso lo que tengo, solo quiero que me déis una idea de cómo hacerlo aunque si teneis código por ahi mejor. Saludos

Comment: que tipo de idea estas buscando. mas alla del codigo extenso o no, la respuesta seria, valida el usuario. que problema especifico tenes para validarlo?

Comment: Seria Utilizar la clásica validación para ver si existe el usuario, realizar un Select con el Id y nombre, si no te devuelve nada la consulta el usuario no existe

Comment: es la clasica validacion de si existe el usuario que no me deje pulsar el boton por que ya existe en la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID_usuario
FROM baseDatos
WHERE ID_usuario = '<NOMBRE A COMPROBAR>'
```

Si esta consulta te devuelve algo, quiere decir que ese usuario ya está registrado.
Es una consulta muy simple, la puedes implementar fácilmente en tu código:

```
// Aquí almacenas el nombre del usuario que quieras comprobar
String usuario;
String consulta = "SELECT ID_usuario FROM baseDatos WHERE ID_usuario = '" + usuario + "'";
```

Espero haber ayudado

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM persona WHERE usuario = ?"))
        {
          $consulta->bind_param("s", $usuario);
        }
        else
        {
          exit();
        }
        $consulta->execute();

        $resultadoConsulta = $consulta->get_result();


if($resultadoConsulta->num_rows == NULL)
        {
          echo 'No EXISTE EL USUARIO';
        }
        else
         {
              echo "El Usuario se encuentra disponible";
         }
```

De esta manera puedes consultar a la BD si el usuario existe o no. Espero haber ayudado, está implementado en PHP y de alguna manera puedes evitar lo que es la InyeccionSQL realizando este tipo de estructura.